# How to use the javascript function to enable/disable the checkbox in rowwise from gridview?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, gridview, checkbox

I want to check the checkbox in rowwise with the some conditions.

- The first condition is when three Checkboxes are selected continuously in same row,it should display the alert popup.("You can't select continuous three hours").
- Next condition is,it shouldn't select more than three checkbox in each row.

I used the below java script,in this code its checking in column wise but I want to check in row wise.

How can I accomplish this condition ?

```
    function CheckCheck() {
        var chkBox = document.getElementById('<%=Gv1.ClientID %>');
        var chkBoxCount = chkBox.getElementsByTagName("input");

        var btn = document.getElementById('<%=btnsubmit.ClientID %>');
        var i = 0;
        var tot = 0;
        for (i = 0; i < chkBoxCount.length; i++) {
            if (chkBoxCount[i].checked) {
                tot = tot + 1;

                if (tot > 2) {
                    alert('Cannot check more than 2 check boxes');
                    chkBoxCount[i].checked = false;
                    return;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

HTML:

```
   <asp:GridView ID="Gv1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" OnRowDataBound="Gv1_RowDataBound">
        <Columns>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="datedif" HeaderText="Day/Hour" SortExpression="datedif" />
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Hour1">
                <EditItemTemplate>
                    <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox1" runat="server" />
                </EditItemTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox1" runat="server" Enabled='<%# Eval("hour1").ToString().Equals("False") %>' />
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Hour2">
                <EditItemTemplate>
                    <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox2" runat="server" />
                </EditItemTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox2" runat="server" Enabled='<%# Eval("hour2").ToString().Equals("False") %>' />
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Hour3">
                <EditItemTemplate>
                    <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox3" runat="server" />
                </EditItemTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox3" runat="server" Enabled='<%# Eval("hour3").ToString().Equals("False") %>' />
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Hour4">
                <EditItemTemplate>
                    <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox4" runat="server" />
                </EditItemTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox4" runat="server" Enabled='<%# Eval("hour4").ToString().Equals("False") %>' />
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Hour5">
                <EditItemTemplate>
                    <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox5" runat="server" />
                </EditItemTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox5" runat="server" Enabled='<%# Eval("hour5").ToString().Equals("False") %>' />
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the collection of `<tr>` (rows) in the gridview and loop through them, looking for check boxes in each row. I would rename your variable chkBox to something like grid, because you are getting the gridView not a checkbox:

```
var grid = document.getElementById('<%=Gv1.ClientID %>');
var gridRows = grid.getElementsByTagName("tr");
for (rowIndex = 0; rowIndex < gridRows.length; rowIndex++) {
    var row = gridRows(rowIndex);
    var chkBoxCount = row.getElementsByTagName("input");

    for (i = 0; i < chkBoxCount.length; i++) {
        if (chkBoxCount[i].checked) {
            tot = tot + 1;

            if (tot > 2) {
                alert('Cannot check more than 2 check boxes');
                chkBoxCount[i].checked = false;
                return;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How to get tag name from grid which you used in the above code ?

Comment: By "tag name from grid" do you mean <table>? If you view the html source you will see that ASP.NET renders the GridView as an html table.

Comment: I'm using gridview not table (<table>) in html. In the above code ("var gridRows = grid.getElementsByTagName("tr");") you used tagname "tr". what is that "tr" ?

Comment: When you use an ASP.NET control like GridView, it is referred to as a server-side control. The server processes it and emits standard html tags that browsers can understand, like <table> and <tr> (table row). To see this, run your page in a browser, right click the the page, and select "View Source" or "View Page Source". That will open the html that the browser received from the server. You won't see the <asp:Gridview> tag, but you will see <table> in its place. Each row of the table is a <tr> tag with each cell of the table being <td> (table definition).

Comment: Yeah thanks I checked it and I understand,But when I use "tr" in the above code it is not working.

Comment: In Visual Studio, place a breakpoint on the first line, set the startup page to the one you are developing, and press F5. When the breakpoint is hit, press F11 to step through each line, and examine the values of each variable to see if they make sense. You should see that gridRows is an object with a count that matches the number of rows in your grid. Continue stepping through and make sure what you see in the debugger matches what you would expect.

Comment: actually i have 5 rows and 6 column and it has 30 check box,in that rows it should not select more that 3 check box and totally it can select minimum of  12 check box

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/74990/discussion-between-kevin-andrid-and-lon-prosser).